# Xamarin Forms Can't assign command to custom button

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have a problem. I am using the following code:
https://github.com/Polarts/CrossFAB

In `page1.xaml` I added the FabMenu like this:

```
<c:FloatingMenu Margin="0, 0, 10, 10" BGColor="#56D7A5" OpenIcon="openFab_icon" CloseIcon="closeFab_icon"
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds=".95,.95" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional">
    <c:FloatingButton x:Name="btnAddItem" BGColor="#59E1FF" IconSrc="add_item_icon" BindingContext="{x:Reference ItemPage}" OnClickCommand="{Binding btnAddItemCommand}" />
</c:FloatingMenu>
```

And in page1.xaml.cs I added the command like this:

```
public partial class Page1 : ContentPage
{

    public static ICommand btnAddItemCommand { get; set; }

    public Page1 ()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
            
        btnAddItemCommand = new Command(OpenNewItemPage);
    }

    private async void OpenNewItemPage()
    {
        await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new NewItemPage());
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I click the button, it gives an error in `FloatingButton.xaml.cs` on the line: `OnClickCommand.Execute(null);`.
The error is:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

This is because according to my code `OnClickCommand` is not set to an instance, so has value null.
The code of FloatingButton.xaml.cs can be found here: https://github.com/Polarts/CrossFAB/blob/master/CrossFAB/Controls/FloatingButton.xaml.cs

How can I fix this?

Comment: what does the stack trace show?  Which item is actually null?

Comment: In stack trace I only see this: `0x8 in MyApp.FabMenu.FloatingButton.<OnPropertyChanged>b__18_0 at C:\Users\me\source\repos\MyApp\MyApp\MyApp\FabMenu\FloatingButton.xaml.cs:94,21` What does that mean?

Comment: the exception originates on line 94 of FloatingButton.xaml.cs

Comment: Then I am again at this line: `OnClickCommand.Execute(null);`, but I don't know why this gives me an error?

Comment: is this a typo in your constructor? `btnAddHomeworkCommand`

Comment: Sorry, thats old code, its now btnAddItemCommand.... I will change it now. My apologies! Altough this doesn't fix the error unfortunately!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you does not bind the command successfully.

In .cs, set the `BindingContext = this;` and do not define the `btnAddItemCommand` as a **static** property:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public ICommand btnAddItemCommand { get; set; }

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        btnAddItemCommand = new Command(OpenNewItemPage);

        BindingContext = this;
    }
    private void OpenNewItemPage()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("OpenNewItemPage");
    }
}
```

In xaml, remove the bindingContext part:

```
<StackLayout>
    <!-- Place new controls here -->
    <Button x:Name="btnAddItem" Text="test" Command="{Binding btnAddItemCommand}" />

</StackLayout>
```